# What's the name of the object, that has an delegate?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, uikit

The delegate is something like the dog from the "master". I'm thinking about the name for an important instance variable that has to hold a weak reference to this "master" of the delegate. Is there any official name for this?

Comment: The words "delegator" and "delegatee"?  Or are you looking for something more technical than this kind of Englishism?

Comment: Maybe. I don't know. I'm looking for an "official" name. Maybe there is some term the Apple Engineers use, and I don't know about.

Comment: Usually one uses a name to describe the 'dog'.  e.g. if you're working with an NSTableView, your instance variable in the delegate could be called 'tableView'

Comment: I would say "the delegating object" but I don't know of any official Apple name.

Answer (score 1):

Apple call it a *host object/class* in the [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide, Cocoa Design Patterns section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html).

Comment: +1 for referencing the documentation, even though this term is rarely used.  I usually say "blah has a delegate".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're thinking of "subordinate"?

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-1044135

Comment: That seems counterintuitive and potentially misleading, as the “subordinate” is the one delegating responsibility to the other object (the delegate).

Answer (score 0):

Your delegate shouldn’t have a reference to the object it is delegate for. Instead the main object should pass itself as a parameter to the delegate methods. That way a single object can be delegate for multiple independent objects.

Comment: For example, a single object being a delegate (or datasource) for an NSTableView -- it **must** have some way to distinguish among them, and a reference seems as good a way as any.

Comment: The data source gets the table view as a parameter, so it doesn’t need to keep a reference.